# JFreeChart issue with dates

Tags: java, date, jfreechart

Hello I am unable to display the dates in a JFreeChart. However the dates are included in the TimeSeries. Here's what I see in the debugger:

[image: The dates are included]

But the only thing I can see is the following:
[image: X axis does not show the dates]

Here's my code:

```
public XYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries(PortfolioValueChart.CHART_NAME_PORTFOLIO);
        for (PriceAction pa : positionPrices.getPrices()) {
            series1.add(pa.date.toRegularTimePeriod(), pa.close);
        }

        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series1);
        return dataset;
    }
```

---

```
JFreeChart portfolioValueChart = PortfolioValueChart.getChart(financialPosition);
ChartPanel portfolioValuePanel = new ChartPanel(portfolioValueChart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use a

```
TimeSeriesChart
```

such as:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(...)
```

With Javadoc:

```
public static JFreeChart createTimeSeriesChart​(String title,
String timeAxisLabel,
String valueAxisLabel,
XYDataset dataset,
boolean legend,
boolean tooltips,
boolean urls)
Creates and returns a time series chart. A time series chart is an XYPlot with a DateAxis for the x-axis and a NumberAxis for the y-axis. The default renderer is an XYLineAndShapeRenderer.
A convenient dataset to use with this chart is a TimeSeriesCollection.

Parameters:
title - the chart title (null permitted).
timeAxisLabel - a label for the time axis (null permitted).
valueAxisLabel - a label for the value axis (null permitted).
dataset - the dataset for the chart (null permitted).
legend - a flag specifying whether or not a legend is required.
tooltips - configure chart to generate tool tips?
urls - configure chart to generate URLs?
Returns:
A time series chart.
```